# How to integrate alfresco authority field control with OOTB ftl?

Tags: forms, user-controls, alfresco, alfresco-share

I am using Alfresco 5.1.0 community version (build version 201605-ga_r127059-b7)

I am trying to integrate user control field with calendar "Add Event" form something like this, https://prnt.sc/jlw6p5

I just get to know the the authority field control ftl (share\WEB-INF\classes\alfresco\site-webscripts\org\alfresco\components\form\controls\authority.ftl) and also add-event form ftl (share\WEB-INF\classes\alfresco\site-webscripts\org\alfresco\modules\create-event.get.html.ftl)

I am not able to find a way how to integrate `authority.ftl` with `create-event.get.html.ftl` so that I can have the user's list on add-event form.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I have another way, You can do the same thing using AIKAU.

You can use AIKAU pickers, or you can create your own AIKAU picker for peoples.

Comment: Hi Vikash, Thanks for your reply. I am not sure how to use  AIKAU pickers, so any reference would be appreciated.

Comment: https://community.alfresco.com/community/ecm/blog/2014/10/31/aikau-simple-picker-updates

Comment: please refer above link and call get users api in the widget